# How to compare each item of List to each item of ListView builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two list called list1 and list2.

list1 is used to show list of students using ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: litems.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     return Text(list1[index]);
    }
  )
```

list1 contains name of all students

now list2 contains name of only few students.
I need to change color of student name if name of student is present in list2. How to compare each item of list2 with each item of `ListView.builder`

list2 is not same as list1. list2 contains only few students name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of how you can do this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: litems.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
    var color;
    if (list2.contains(list1[index])) {
      //The name is present in list2
      color = Colors.green;
    } else {
      //The name is not present in list2
      color = Colors.black;
    }
    return Text(
      list1[index],
      style: TextStyle(
        color: color,
      ),
    );
  }
)
```

You can do more inside the if / else statements to customise your widget.